# How to execute Javascript code in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console

I have a little application that generates some Javascript code, what can be executed on websites. To execute this code I'm using browser console and for Firefox it works well, but I can't figure out how to make it work with the Chrome browser.

In Firefox I'm generating this Javascript code:

```
javascript:var els = document.getElementById('video');els.style="";var none = document.getElementById('slika'); none.style="display:none;"
```

I open the console (CTRL-SHIFT-K), paste it, press ENTER and then the code is doing it's job.
I tried with Chrome via console (CTRL-SHIFT-J), in the address bar, but nothing happens. If I'm trying in the console all I get is this line:

```
"display:none;"
```

What does it stand for? Is there some syntax error?

If i try in the address bar, the browser redirects me to google and executes a query with the javascript code as search value :)

So I'm stuck with Chrome...

Can someone help me out, please? Thank you very much!

Comment: It's just displaying the value of the last expression you entered, which is `none.style="display:none;"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `javascript:` prefix if you're entering the code in the console.

Also, I'm not sure if `none.style="display:none;"` is valid.  Try `none.style.display="none";` if you're having problems with it.